# Using Visual GDB to migrate MSVC2010 code to linux

Tags: linux, windows, visual-studio-2010, mfc, visualgdb

I am trying to migrate my MSVC code which uses MFC in shared dll to linux.Is there any way to migrate the whole project apart from rewriting the window specific files since my project is huge and contains more than 200 header and cpp files.
I tried using qt  but there was no direct way.
Now i am trying to use Visual GDB for the same but i am not sure how to do it.

Comment: Google "mfc linux". Visual GDB won't help.

Comment: I have doubts that using WINE lib may effect the performance. Can please comment your opinion on the same.

Comment: What you're trying to do is a very difficult task. IMO there is no easy solution. Bad performance is the least of your problems here, but Winelib does not necessarily imply bad performance.